# Is there a way to optimize these for loops?

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

There has to be a way to optimize this code in Python..

I have a function called `calculate` that needs to be run twice by a different dictionary (`operators1` and `operators2`).

```py
def main(string):
  for op1 in operators1:
    return calculate(string, op1)
    
  for op2 in operators2:
    return calculate(string, op2)
```

I simplified the code in this example a lot, but I have a bunch of other if-statements and for-loops in there, which is the exact same for both for-loops. So looking at that, I see a lot of duplicate lines. And I don't like duplicate lines, so I tried to optimize this as 1 for loop.

```py
def main(string):
  for x in range(2):
    for op in operators+(x+1):
      return calculate(string, op)
```

Unfortunately, `operators+(x+1)` or something similar didn't work. It didn't actually add the 1 or 2 on there before looking at it as a variable for a dictionary.

Next thing I tried is putting both dictionaries in a new array `opsArray`

```py
operatorsList = [operators1, operators2]

def main(string):
  for x in range(2):
    for op in operatorsList[x]:
      return calculate(string, op)
```

This didn't work either so now I'm clueless.

I'm just trying to combine the 2 for-loops in the first example into a single for-loops to avoid duplicate if-statements.
Can someone tell me if what I'm trying to do here is actually possible and how it would be done?

Comment: What is ops? What is sum? You should use a different variable name than sum since that is a keyword.

Comment: We need an example of sum as well as a char1 and char2.

Comment: @Mark I simplified the code and added a bit more information. I hope that helps.

Comment: @Kosaro I don't think the type of variables used here should matter right? I renamed the variables not though, so I hope that helps

Comment: How about `result=calculate(...)` instead of `return calculate(...)`? The latter returns without coming back to do another.

Comment: @jpf I actually do loop through it a couple of times. I also need return to stop the function after it matched with one of the if-statements in my code. But either way, it shouldn't matter for the question right?

Comment: Why dont you loop over `[operators1, operators2]` instead of `range(2)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you where half way there, and so close to getting the answer.

```
operatorsList = [operators1, operators2]

def main(string):
  for elem in operatorslist:
    for op in elem:
      return calculate(string, op)
```

It just iterates through the dictionary and creates a dictionary `elem` of which is equal to operators1 and operators2